# Swift variable name with ` (backtick)

Tags: swift, alamofire

I was browsing Alamofire sources and found a variable name that is backtick escaped in [this source file](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Source/SessionManager.swift)

```
open static let `default`: SessionManager = {
    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    configuration.httpAdditionalHeaders = SessionManager.defaultHTTPHeaders

    return SessionManager(configuration: configuration)
}()
```

However in places where variable is used there are no backticks. What's the purpose of backticks?

Removing the backticks results in the error:

> Keyword 'default' cannot be used as an identifier here

Answer (score 60, accepted):

According to the [Swift documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/LexicalStructure.html#ID412) :

> To use a reserved word as an identifier, put a backtick (`` ` ``)before and after it. For example, `class` is not a valid identifier, but `` `class` `` is valid. The backticks are not considered part of the identifier; `` `x` `` and `x` have the same meaning.

In your example, `default` is a Swift reserved keyword, that's why backticks are needed.

Answer (score 10):

Example addendum to [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41503795/4573247), regarding using reserved word identifiers, after they have been correctly declared using backticks.

> The backticks are not considered part of the identifier; `x` and x
>   have the same meaning.

Meaning we needn't worry about using the backticks after identifier declaration (however we *may*):

```
enum Foo {
    case `var`
    case `let`
    case `class`
    case `try`
}

/* "The backticks are not considered part of the identifier; 
    `x` and x have the same meaning"                          */
let foo = Foo.var
let bar = [Foo.let, .`class`, .try]
print(bar) // [Foo.let, Foo.class, Foo.try]
```

Answer (score 8):

Simply put, by using backticks you are allowed to use
reserved words for variable names etc.

```
var var = "This will generate an error" 

var `var` = "This will not!"
```