# `self` in Swift closure

Tags: swift, closures

I want to understant `self` in Swift closure.
For Ex -

```
() -> Void = { [weak self] in
    guard let `self` = self else { 
        self.callMethod2()
    }
    self.callMethod3()
}
```

Why we use backtick here?
Is it good programming practice?
How self is weakly captured here?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41503740/swift-variable-name-with-backtick

Comment: Note that [soon you'll be allowed to say](https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/15306) `guard let self = self else {...}` without the backticks – the parser will treat `self` as an ordinary identifier in that context, allowing it to be rebound :)

Comment: Further discussion on the matter: https://forums.swift.org/t/the-future-of-weak-self-rebinding/10846

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`self` is a reserved word in Swift. Since you're creating a new local var called self you need to mark it with back-ticks, as explained in the link from rmaddy.

Note that the usual convention for mapping weak self to a strong var is to use the name `strongSelf`:

```
() -> Void = { [weak self] in
    guard let strongSelf = self else { 
        //your code to call self.callMethod2() can't succeed inside the guard (since in that case weak self is nil)
        //self.callMethod2()
        return   //You must have a statement like return, break, fatalEror, or continue that breaks the flow of control if the guard statement fails
    }
    strongSelf.callMethod3()
}
```

Comment: @Hamish thanks for cleaning up my code formatting. Somewhat I forgot the code block indent...

Answer (score 7):

Swift 4.2 recently adopted a proposal to add this to the language:

```
guard let self = self else { return }
```

The proposed solution entails allowing self to be upgraded from a weak reference to a strong reference using optional binding.

For more details refer swift evolution proposal [SE-0079](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0079-upgrade-self-from-weak-to-strong.md)