# Swift Codable with reserved word

Tags: swift, codable

I have a situation where the JSON being returned from an API has a field named extension, which is a reserved word in Swift. My codable is blowing up when I try to use it.

I've searched for the last two hours, but I can't seem to find any solution.

Has anyone run into this before:

```
public struct PhoneNumber: Codable {

    var phoneNumber: String
    var extension: String
    var isPrimary: Bool
    var usageType: Int
}
```

Keyword 'extension' cannot be used as an identifier here

Comment: You can use backticks as shown in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41504472/4056108)

Comment: Thanks @chirag90 that solution worked perfectly.

Comment: You are most welcome @Bryan You should mark one of the answer below which worked for you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift variable name with \` (backtick)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41503740/swift-variable-name-with-backtick)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've had similar problems with 'return'.  You can get around with CodingKeys.

```
public struct PhoneNumber: Codable {
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case phoneNumber
        case extensionString = "extension"
        case isPrimary
        case usageType
    }

  var phoneNumber: String
  var extensionString: String
  var isPrimiry: Bool
  var usageType: Int
}
```

As you cant call a property 'extension' you name it something similar but use the CodingKeys to tell you object what the key in the JSON is.

Comment: @Bryan this would be a better way than backticks

Answer (score 18):

Just add backticks to the variable name to make the compiler think that it's a variable, not a keyword.

```
var `extension`: String
```

Comment: Wow. I had no idea that was the case!